# Atlassian Community

Tags: jenkins, jira, integration, jira-rest-api, connection-refused

We were looking for a plugin that could help us to integrate Jira and Jenkins. Thanks to plugin `Jira issue updater.` But while configuring this plugin, we are facing below error

Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM

### Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Demo

### JIRA Update Build Step

> Unable to connect to REST service java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused (Connection refused)Finished: SUCCESS

All configurations are mentioned in the following image

[image: All configurations are mentioned in attached image]

Is there anyone who is also facing the same error? Or need support from Stack Overflow to whisper out this error?

Comment: The `Jira REST Base URL` you configured doesn't seem right, according to https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-issue-updater-plugin it should be only up to .../rest/api/latest (i.e. drop the "issue/RN-6").

Comment: From the box running Jenkins is it possible to connect to Jira by other means (does e.g. running `curl https://whatever/you/configured/as/rest/base/url`) on the Jenkins work? If that also doesn't work then this is an infrastructure issue - e.g. a firewall preventing the connection).

Comment: Thanks for your time and advice... As per your first comment, I removed the issue/RN-6, but still, I am facing the same issue. Talking about the second comment-- I have configured docker images for Jira and Jenkins, and both images are in the same network. I could able to ping Jira's IP from Jenkins instance.

Comment: pinging is not the same as actually trying a web request with curl. Firewalls may let the ping through but block the http req.

Comment: As I am using docker images, so I configured a container IP, and It is working smoothly...  Thanks @IstvanSzekeres for your answers:)